# Is there software that can automatically create pictures from a video?

Tags: windows, video, images

I use Windows 10 and prefer free software. After I define time intervals (e.g. every 5 or 10 s), is there any that can capture pictures from a video file? Undoubtedly it's too unproductive for me to hit `Print Screen` manually, especially for lengthy videos!

Answer (score 3):

Use [FFMPEG](https://ffmpeg.org/). It's the famous tool for manipulating video and image files. To extract images every 5 seconds run the command like this

```
ffmpeg -i videofile.mp4 -vf fps=1/5 img%03d.jpg
```

`fps` is the number of frames per second, so fps=1 will save an image every second, and fps=1/60 will do that every minute. See [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Answer (score 0):

You can give [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org/) a try. It's a free and open source video editing tool. It works on [FFMPEG](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

To start with there are also some tutorials: https://www.shotcut.org/tutorials/